# How do you make responsive logos that change completely when the screensize changes?

Tags: html, css, svg

I was quite amazed at [Responsive Logos](http://responsivelogos.co.uk/), when you resize the browser the image width doesn't just say 100% but the image itself changes. It's not a font. I think its a svg image, but how Im dont exactly sure how he managed to make the image change. Is it via the CSS at the bottom of the source code:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 15em) {
    .logo1, .logo2, .logo3, .logo4, .logo5, .logo6, .logo7, .logo8 {background-position: left -900px;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 28em) {
    .logo1, .logo2, .logo3, .logo4, .logo5, .logo6, .logo7, .logo8 {background-position: left -600px;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 45em){
    .logo1, .logo2, .logo3, .logo4, .logo5, .logo6, .logo7, .logo8 {background-position: left -300px;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 60em){
    .logo1, .logo2, .logo3, .logo4, .logo5, .logo6, .logo7, .logo8 {background-position: left 0px;}
 }
```

Thanks in advance for your helps!

Comment: i don't think this is the place to ask that, but i'll answer you anyway: the background image is actually a really long image with different logos on it. the media queries:**@media screen and (min-width:15em){properties}**set the different offsets to the image with the different window sizes so the logos can be seen,if my answer wasn't clear enough you should look up media queries on google or something.

Comment: the is a sprite it can be a `.png` it will be simple if you know @media queries (sprite contains all the images in one image) you only need to give `background position` to show which area you want to show of the image

Answer (score 1):

The background image is an [image sprite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_(computer_graphics)).

The sprite includes several versions of the logo, each at a different position. `background-position` is used to horizontally shift the image by `0px`, `300px`, `600px`, or `900px` to select the desired logo.